# Работа с CSV файлами. Каждый подмассив итогового массива относится к названию предмета. Вывести название предмета и средний балл по убыванию

Tags: python, csv

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Создать массив, заполненный данными из данного csv файла. Очистить все лишние элементы из массива(должны остаться только числа). Найти среднее арифметическое каждого подмассива.
Каждый подмассив итогового массива относится к названию предмета. Необходимо вывести название предмета и средний балл в порядке убывания.

Как вывести название предмета и средний балл по убыванию?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.genfromtxt("poit16.csv", 
delimiter=",", dtype=float)

print("Исходный массив:")
print(arr)

cleaned_arr = arr[~np.isnan(arr)]
print("Очищенный массив:")
print(cleaned_arr)

subarrays = np.split(cleaned_arr, np.where(np.diff(np.isnan(cleaned_arr)))[0] + 1)


averages = [np.mean(subarray) for  subarray in subarrays]

print("Среднее арифметическое каждого подмассива:")
print(averages)
```

Comment: вы бы пример данных в воспроизводимом виде  привели.